# Get File name from a variable

Tags: batch-file

i am totally new to batch file programming so please forgive me if this is plain obvious. Say i have a `c:\some\path\someFile.extension` string stored in *TheFileToPass* and i am invoking another exe from the same batch file such that i should only pass it the File name deducted from *TheFileToPass* (i.e, *someFile*).

A pseudo code of what i am trying to do:

> string TheFileToPass = "c:\some\path\someFile.extension"
>
> call external_tool.exe TheFileToPass.GetFileNameWithoutExtension()

By searching online i came to know that **%~nI** can resolve the problem but how can i use it on the *TheFileToPass* variable? i have tried the following but nothing works:

> echo %%~TheFileToPass
>
> echo %%~n%TheFileToPass%

**EDIT**

Okay, i'll try to be more descriptive. i have a couple of "local variables" defined in our batch file:

```
set someFlag1=
set someFlag2=
set someFile=
```

Then i parse command line arguments and put them inside above declared variables. The batch file can have variable number of command line arguments so the position of values can vary based upon some predefined rules. In nutshell, we cannot be certain that %1, %2, %3 (etc.) which one will always have the filepath. Anyway, based upon predefined rules, we parse the command line arguments (using SHIFT loop technique) and keep that information in our variables: someFlag1, someFlag2 and someFile.

Now, someFile contains fullpath for the file, e.g.: "c:\some\path\file.txt". And we wish to invoke an external exe and pass it the file name from the contents of someFile variable ("file", in this case).

So what operation do we operate on the "someFile" variable that we only get the filename from the fullpath?

Comment: Your explanation is difficult to follow here - can you give some examples?  `filename=one.txt` `string-inside-one.txt=apple.orange` `need-to-launch=two.exe one.apple`  Is that it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say you are iterating through the parameters of batch file using shift to get the file name. So in some moment, you will have something as

```
set "someFile=%~1"
```

Then, all you need to add is the extraction of filename to later use it

```
set "onlyFileName=%~n1"
```

Comment: Sweet! Yes, that works. Thank You! Before i mark the question resolved, i'd still like to know could we perform a similar operation directly onto a variable which contains path information? If Yes, what would be the syntax?

Comment: This will work on a parameter variable (%1 in this case) with only a filename or a full filepath. We are asking cmd to retrieve only the filename part. If the fullpath is in a standard variable (`set some=...`), the answer from npocmaka (`for %%f in ("%some%") do set fileName=%%~nf`) will get the file name. Note the sintax is the same, % or %% depending of the variable, ~ , n (get file name) and the reference to the variable (1 in the parameter case, f in the for case)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you are passing the file to the batch file.

You either pass on command line and use %~dpn1 (you'll want the path) or if hard coded pass to a function in the bat and use the same %~dpn1.

Type

```
call /?
set /?
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for %f in ("%TheFileToPass %") do call external_tool.exe %~nf.GetFileNameWithoutExtension()
```